# p:autoComplete lost value after form validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use a PrimeFaces `p:autoComplete` component. It works incorrect after form validation. If I for example leave empty any other component in the form and after that get a message from validation then autoComplete lost a value. And converter is trying to convert a selected object, in the result autoComplete return null value.

```
    public class OrganizationConverter implements Converter {

        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {

            Organization organization = null;

            if(value != null && value.trim().length() >0) {
                 try{
                     try {
                         organization = DAO.OrganizationDAO.findOrganizationByCode(value);}
                     catch (IOException ex) {
                         Logger.getLogger(OrganizationConverter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
                    }
                 catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid theme."));
                }}

            System.out.println("conwerter: value"+value+ "object"+organization);

            return organization;
    }

   public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {

            if(object != null) {
                return String.valueOf((object));
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }   
    }
```

<

```html
<p:autoComplete id="organizationAutoComlete" minQueryLength="2" forceSelection="true" selectLimit="1" autocomplete="" style="width:338px;" value="#{addTrainingBean.re0.training.organization}" converter="organizationConverter" completeMethod="#{addTrainingBean.completeOrganization}" immediate="false" var="theme" itemValue="#{theme.code}" itemLabel="#{theme.name}"  scrollHeight="400" dropdown="true" dropdownMode="current" required="true" requiredMessage="Uzupełnij pole Organizator">
       <p:column headerText="Kod:">
          <h:outputText value="#{theme.code}" />
       </p:column>
  </p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: Hi, [mcve] please. See also [ask]

Comment: Which version of PrimeFaces are you using? Possibly affected by https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/20 or https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1476 ?

Comment: Hi I use PrimeFaces 6.1, i solve this issu changing Converter but do not like this solution. I filtered String to get object id, then locking by id. This solution based on String filtered, and I do not think it is a good way.